# How can I access Jupyter Notebook on single port (8888) running on multiple docker containers ?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, docker-swarm

I'm running Web application outside of the container and installation of Jupyter Notebook is done in a docker container. Now I would like to access Jupyter Notebook on the web page, running in multiple Docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

This use case calls for having a way to route to a specific container based on URL path. So, you can use something like [`traefik`](https://docs.traefik.io/) to act as a gateway to your many docker containers.

Each of your jupyter container should have a different `Path:` label and that would let traefik route traffic to the correct container when making requests like `http://hostname/jupyter1` for example.

Check the traefik matcher [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#matchers) for more information on the labels required.